# Draft gmail attachments appear in trash folder when javamail is used

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail, imap, gmail-imap

I'm using javamail to read emails from gmail Trash folder and if there is email in Draft folder with attachments then these attachments appear in Trash folder.

Steps to reproduce:
1) create new email with attachment(s) and close it, it appears in Draft folder. 2) Read emails from Trash folder using program below. Attachment(s) from draft email appear. If I open Trash folder in browser I don't see these attachments. Do you know why attachment appear in Trash folder when emails are read using javamail?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;


public class MailClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MailClient client = new MailClient();
        client.execute();
    }

    void execute() throws MessagingException, IOException {
        String[] credentials = new String[] {"name@gmail.com", "password"};
        boolean debug = false;

        Folder folder = null;
        Store store = null;
        try {
            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            session.setDebug(debug);
            store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", credentials[0], credentials[1]);
            folder = store.getFolder("[Gmail]/Trash");
            folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

            Message messages[] = folder.getMessages();
            System.out.println("No of Messages : " + folder.getMessageCount());
            System.out.println("No of Unread Messages : " + folder.getUnreadMessageCount());
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; ++i) {
                System.out.println("MESSAGE #" + (i + 1) + ":");
                Message msg = messages[i];

                String from = "unknown";
                if (msg.getReplyTo().length >= 1) {
                    from = msg.getReplyTo()[0].toString();
                } else if (msg.getFrom().length >= 1) {
                    from = msg.getFrom()[0].toString();
                }
                String subject = msg.getSubject();
                System.out.println(subject);
                msg.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);
            }
        } finally {
            if (folder != null) {
                folder.close(true);
            }
            if (store != null) {
                store.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  The "ghost" attachments are shown from IMAP's ponit of view, yet they are not shown in the gmail client.  Not sure exactly what google is doing here.

Answer (score 0):

Your program doesn't do anything with attachments.  Why do you believe the attachments for the draft message, but not the message itself, appear in the Trash folder?  And what message in the Trash folder are those attachments attached to?

How are you creating the Draft message?  Through the Gmail web interface?  Is it possible that Gmail is saving multiple drafts of your draft message, and the old drafts are being moved into the Trash folder, with only the latest draft left in the Drafts folder?

Comment: I create draft message with attachments through the Gmail web interface. Trash folder is empty - that's what I see in web interface. Then I want to read all messages from Trash folder using application I have shown. I expect no messages because Trash folder is empty, however application receives attachments (as messages) from message saved in Draft folder. It looks like all attachments of  messages in Draft folder are moved/copied into Trash folder but they are hidden.

Comment: Could be, I have no idea how Gmail works.  Are the attachments also on the messages in the Drafts folder?  Do the messages in the Trash folder have any flags?  If you empty your Trash folder, do these messages go away?